# p:selectBooleanButtons auto-submits inside the footer facet of a p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my web app, I have List belonging to different Project. I am displaying all of the Search available to the user using a p:selectOneMenu. I have the converters implemented for the Search class and it is working as expected. Now, I wanted the users to be able to see Search by Project. I decided to have p:selectBooleanButton wrapped with p:repeat whose value is tied to List so that I have a p:selectBooleanButton for each Project available. This selectBooleanButtons are placed in the footer facet of the p:selectOneMenu, so that users can easily toggle those Project buttons and see/hide Search of any Project they want. I went with this approach because we only have two Projects which are fixed (or atleast will be the only ones for some time).

The problem is that whenever the container containing this p:selectOneMenu is updated, the selectBooleanButtons are automatically set to false, and even when I toggle it when the booleanButton is false, it sets itself to true and automatically sets itself back to false. I am guessing the value is being submitted twice, due to it being inside a p:selectOneMenu.

I just want a nice approach to debug this, I tried setting breakpoints in the backing bean getter/setter methods, and watching the inspector pane for POST request but this does not really open up the problem for me. Maybe I am approaching it the wrong way.

**SelectOneMenu**

```
                    <p:selectOneMenu
                        label="Quick Access"
                        widgetVar="quickAccessDropDownWidget"
                        style="width: 150px;"
                        class="available-search-list"
                        converter="searchConverter"
                        filter="true"
                        filterMatchMode="contains"
                        alwaysDisplayLabel="true"
                        placeholder="#{not empty deepBean.quickAccessSearchList ? 'Search Name' : 'No Available Searches'}"
                        editable="false"
                        var="searchItem"
                        title="Available Searches for Quick use"> 
                        <f:selectItems value="#{deepBean.quickAccessSearchList}" 
                                       class="test" 
                                       var="search" 
                                       itemLabel="#{search}" 
                                       itemValue="#{search}"
                                       />
                        <p:column style="width: 100%;" class="available-search-list-items">
                            <span class="row-container">
                                <i id="" class="#{searchItem.isPublic ? 'pi pi-globe' : 'pi pi-user'}"/> 
                                <p:outputLabel id="searchName" value="#{searchItem.name}" style="margin-left: 10px;"/>
                                <p:tooltip for="searchName" escape="false" value="#{deepBean.getTooltipInfoForSearch(searchItem)}"/>
                                <p:outputPanel>
                                    <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-pencil" 
                                                     class="btn ui-button" 
                                                     style="margin-left: 20px;"
                                                     process="@this"
                                                     onclick="onClickSearchEdit('#{searchItem.name}')"/>
                                    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-send" 
                                                     class="btn ui-button-success" 
                                                     style="margin-left: 5px;"
                                                     onclick="onClickSearchQuickRun('#{searchItem.name}')"
                                                     process="@this"
                                                     update="@(.results-view-panel)"/>
                                </p:outputPanel>
                            </span>
                        </p:column>
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Search for:" style="font-style: italic; margin-left: 5px;"/>
                            <p:outputPanel class="project-toggle-btns">
                                <p:repeat id="projectSelect" 
                                          value="#{deepBean.projectList}" 
                                          var="project"
                                          >
                                    <p:selectBooleanButton id="project"
                                                           value="#{project.selected}"
                                                           onLabel="#{project.name}" offLabel="#{project.name}" 
                                                           onIcon="fa fa-check"
                                                           offIcon="fa fa-square-o"
                                                           style="margin: 5px; padding: 5px;" >

                                        <p:ajax listener="#{deepBean.toggleProjectSelection()}"
                                                process="@this"
                                                update="@(.dash-board)"
                                                oncomplete="PF('quickAccessDropDownWidget').show();"/>

                                    </p:selectBooleanButton>
                                    <ui:debug/>
                                </p:repeat>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Can you add some code to reproduce your error? Maybe beans classes, main xhtml where SelectOneMenu is used, PF version, to have a minimal reproducible example.